# Arranging dynamically created controls on a web form

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, layout, controls

I am a newbie if it comes to web site development. I would like to create a web form that would contain controls defined in an XML file. This means that I am going to read the XML file within the Page_Load function and dynamically create and name all controls as defined in the file. This seams to be very easy.

I have, however, another problem, namely the layout. When I add a new control to my form, it is placed next to the control that was created previously. How can I place them one below another or put some spaces before and between them? I thought using the PlaceHolder control would help me, but I couldn't find any properties that would change the position of the controls parented by it.

Here is how I create a single control:

```
Label lbl = new Label();
lbl.ID = "lbl";
lbl.Text = "Test";
PlaceHolderMain.Controls.Add(lbl);
```

Thanks for your help in advance,

Mariusz.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Add additional controls such as a [Literal](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=asp.net+literal+control&aq=1&oq=ASP.Net+liter) Control where the text is the HTML you want such as a `<BR/>` tag or `nbsp;` in between the controls that have been added.
2. Have multiple Placeholder controls for each appropriate section.
3. Use CSS to position the controls where you want them. I am not a CSS expert but this can be done but it requires an understanding of CSS positioning.
4. Add the controls into a parent control such as a table so you can add the controls into a tabel cell within a row.  It would mean creating Rows and Cells to add to the table but it would give you more control over the layout.

Hope this gives you a few ideas that can help.

Comment: I think that just about covers most of the available options. Great answer! +1